# Three.js runs slow if I load a server file

Tags: javascript, php, server, three.js

I have a three.js game, I want to be able to load information about different players in the game by loading the file with either php or ajax. But if I load a file at all, the three.js game gets very slow and choppy.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php
$file1 = fopen("Profiles/person1.player", "r");
$file2 = fopen("Profiles/person2.player", "r");

$text1 = fread($file1, filesize("Profiles/person1.player"));
$text2 = fread($file2, filesize("Profiles/person2.player"));
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Three.js</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <style>
  body{
   margin: 0%;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  head{
   margin: 0px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="three.js"></script>
  <script src="prefabs.js"></script>
  <script>
var seq1 = "<?php echo $text1; ?>";
var seq2 = "<?php echo $text2; ?>";

seq1.split(", ");
seq2.split(", ");

for (var i = 0; i < seq1.length; i++){
    seq1[i] = parseFloat(seq1[i]);
}
for (var j = 0; j < seq2.length; j++){
    seq2[j] = parseFloat(seq2[j]);
}
var sequence1 = seq1;
var sequence2 = seq2;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
camera.position.z = 0;
camera.position.x = 15;
camera.position.y = 7.5;

scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));
var directional = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
directional.position.set(3, 10, 3);
scene.add(directional);

var player1 = Player(0xbc3232);
scene.add(player1.body);
player1.body.position.set(0, 0, 5);
var player2 = Player(0x4286f4);
scene.add(player2.body);
player2.body.position.set(0, 0, -5);

var ground = new THREE.Mesh(
 new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 1, 20),
 new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xdddddd})
);
ground.position.set(0, -2, 0);

var boxingRing = {
 one: new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.75, 0.75, 10, 16),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()
 ),
 two: new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.75, 0.75, 10, 16),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()
 ),
 three: new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.75, 0.75, 10, 16),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()
 ),
 four: new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.75, 0.75, 10, 16),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()
 ),
 beams: {
  one: new THREE.Mesh(
   new THREE.TorusGeometry(13.5, 0.3, 16, 4),
   new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xbc3232})
  ),
  two: new THREE.Mesh(
   new THREE.TorusGeometry(13.5, 0.3, 16, 4),
   new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0x4286f4})
  ),
  three: new THREE.Mesh(
   new THREE.TorusGeometry(13.5, 0.3, 16, 4),
   new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xdddddd})
  ),
 }
};



ground.add(boxingRing.one);
boxingRing.one.position.set(-9.5, 0, -9.5);
ground.add(boxingRing.two);
boxingRing.two.position.set(9.5, 0, -9.5);
ground.add(boxingRing.three);
boxingRing.three.position.set(-9.5, 0, 9.5);
ground.add(boxingRing.four);

boxingRing.beams.one.rotation.set(Math.PI/2, 0, Math.PI/4);
boxingRing.four.position.set(9.5, 0, 9.5);
ground.add(boxingRing.beams.one);
boxingRing.beams.one.position.set(0, 2, 0);

boxingRing.beams.two.rotation.set(Math.PI/2, 0, Math.PI/4);
ground.add(boxingRing.beams.two);
boxingRing.beams.two.position.set(0, 3, 0);

boxingRing.beams.three.rotation.set(Math.PI/2, 0, Math.PI/4);
ground.add(boxingRing.beams.three);
boxingRing.beams.three.position.set(0, 4, 0);

scene.add(ground);

function GameLoop(){
    requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);
 PlayerControl();
 CameraControl();
 Render();
 lightHolder.rotation.x += 0.01;
}
function Render(){
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
function CameraControl(){
 var target = new THREE.Vector3(
  (player1.body.position.x + player2.body.position.x)/2,
  (player1.body.position.y + player2.body.position.y)/2,
  (player1.body.position.z + player2.body.position.z)/2
 );
 camera.lookAt(target);
 var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(player1.body.position.x - player2.body.position.x, 2) + Math.pow(player1.body.position.z - player2.body.position.z, 2));
 camera.fov = dist*5;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
function PlayerControl(){
 player1.body.lookAt(player2.body.position);
 player2.body.lookAt(player1.body.position);
 Anim1();
 Anim2();
}

var animations = [
[//0 = charge, 1 = shoot, 2 = block//
 //Left Hand Pos
 {
  x: [2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5],
  y: [1, 1, 1, 1],
  z: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
 },
 //Right Hand Pos
 {
  x: [-2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5],
  y: [1, 1, 1, 1],
  z: [0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.5]
 },
 //Left Hand Rot
 {
  x: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  z: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 },
 //Right Hand Rot
 {
  x: [0, 0, -70, -70],
  y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  z: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 },
 //Shield Scale
 {
  x: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  z: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 },
 //Gun Scale
 {
  x: [0, 1, 1, 1],
  y: [0, 1, 1, 1],
  z: [0, 1, 1, 1]
 }
],
[
 //Left Hand Pos
 {
  x: [2.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
  y: [1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
  z: [0.5, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5]
 },
 //Right Hand Pos
 {
  x: [-2.5, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25],
  y: [1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
  z: [0.5, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5]
 },
 //Left Hand Rot
 {
  x: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  z: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 },
 //Right Hand Rot
 {
  x: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  z: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 },
 //Shield Scale
 {
  x: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  z: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 },
 //Gun Scale
 {
  x: [0, 0, 1, 1],
  y: [0, 0, 1, 1],
  z: [0, 0, 1, 1]
 }
],
[
 //Left Hand Pos
 {
  x: [1.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
  y: [1, 1, 1, 1],
  z: [0.5, 2, 2, 2]
 },
 //Right Hand Pos
 {
  x: [-1.5, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25],
  y: [1, 1, 1, 1],
  z: [0.5, 2, 2, 2]
 },
 //Left Hand Rot
 {
  x: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  z: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 },
 //Right Hand Rot
 {
  x: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  z: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 },
 //Shield Scale
 {
  x: [0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5],
  y: [0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5],
  z: [0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5]
 },
 //Gun Scale
 {
  x: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  y: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  z: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 }
]];

var frame1 = 1;
var lastFrame1 = 0;
var time1 = 0;
var clip1 = 0;
var lastClip1 = 0;
var speed = 10;
function Anim1(){
 time1++;
 if (time1 == speed){
  time1 = 0;
  lastFrame1 = frame1;
  frame1++;
  if (frame1 == 4){
   frame1 = 0;
   lastClip1 = clip1;
   clip1++;
   if (clip1 == sequence1.length){
    clip1 = 0;
   }
  }
 }
 if (frame1 !== 0){
  lastClip1 = clip1;
 }
 var values = {
  leftPos: {
   x: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][0].x[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][0].x[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2,
   y: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][0].y[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][0].y[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2,
   z: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][0].z[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][0].z[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2
  },
  rightPos: {
   x: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][1].x[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][1].x[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2,
   y: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][1].y[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][1].y[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2,
   z: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][1].z[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][1].z[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2
  },
  leftRot: {
   x: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][2].x[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][2].x[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2*Math.PI/90,
   y: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][2].y[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][2].y[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2*Math.PI/90,
   z: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][2].z[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][2].z[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2*Math.PI/90
  },
  rightRot: {
   x: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][3].x[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][3].x[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2*Math.PI/90,
   y: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][3].y[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][3].y[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2*Math.PI/90,
   z: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][3].z[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][3].z[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2*Math.PI/90
  },
  shieldScale: {
   x: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][4].x[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][4].x[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2,
   y: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][4].y[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][4].y[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2,
   z: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][4].z[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][4].z[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2
  },
  gunScale: {
   x: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][5].x[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][5].x[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2,
   y: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][5].y[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][5].y[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2,
   z: ((animations[sequence1[clip1]][5].z[frame1]/speed*time1) + (animations[sequence1[lastClip1]][5].z[lastFrame1]/speed*(speed-time1)))/2
  }
 };
 
 player1.hands.l.position.set(
  values.leftPos.x,
  values.leftPos.y,
  values.leftPos.z
 );
 player1.hands.r.position.set(
  values.rightPos.x,
  values.rightPos.y,
  values.rightPos.z
 );
 player1.hands.l.rotation.set(
  values.leftRot.x,
  values.leftRot.y,
  values.leftRot.z
 );
 player1.hands.r.rotation.set(
  values.rightRot.x,
  values.rightRot.y,
  values.rightRot.z
 );
 player1.shield.scale.set(
  values.shieldScale.x,
  values.shieldScale.y,
  values.shieldScale.z
 );
 player1.pistol.scale.set(
  values.gunScale.x,
  values.gunScale.y,
  values.gunScale.z
 );
}

var frame2 = 1;
var lastFrame2 = 0;
var time2 = 0;
var clip2 = 0;
var lastClip2 = 0;
var speed = 10;
function Anim2(){
 time2++;
 if (time2 == speed){
  time2 = 0;
  lastFrame2 = frame2;
  frame2++;
  if (frame2 == 4){
   frame2 = 0;
   lastClip2 = clip2;
   clip2++;
   if (clip2 == sequence2.length){
    clip2 = 0;
   }
  }
 }
 if (frame2 !== 0){
  lastClip2 = clip2;
 }
 var values = {
  leftPos: {
   x: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][0].x[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][0].x[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2,
   y: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][0].y[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][0].y[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2,
   z: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][0].z[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][0].z[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2
  },
  rightPos: {
   x: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][1].x[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][1].x[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2,
   y: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][1].y[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][1].y[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2,
   z: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][1].z[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][1].z[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2
  },
  leftRot: {
   x: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][2].x[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][2].x[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2*Math.PI/90,
   y: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][2].y[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][2].y[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2*Math.PI/90,
   z: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][2].z[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][2].z[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2*Math.PI/90
  },
  rightRot: {
   x: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][3].x[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][3].x[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2*Math.PI/90,
   y: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][3].y[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][3].y[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2*Math.PI/90,
   z: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][3].z[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][3].z[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2*Math.PI/90
  },
  shieldScale: {
   x: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][4].x[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][4].x[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2,
   y: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][4].y[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][4].y[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2,
   z: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][4].z[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][4].z[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2
  },
  gunScale: {
   x: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][5].x[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][5].x[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2,
   y: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][5].y[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][5].y[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2,
   z: ((animations[sequence2[clip2]][5].z[frame2]/speed*time2) + (animations[sequence2[lastClip2]][5].z[lastFrame2]/speed*(speed-time2)))/2
  }
 };
 
 player2.hands.l.position.set(
  values.leftPos.x,
  values.leftPos.y,
  values.leftPos.z
 );
 player2.hands.r.position.set(
  values.rightPos.x,
  values.rightPos.y,
  values.rightPos.z
 );
 player2.hands.l.rotation.set(
  values.leftRot.x,
  values.leftRot.y,
  values.leftRot.z
 );
 player2.hands.r.rotation.set(
  values.rightRot.x,
  values.rightRot.y,
  values.rightRot.z
 );
 player2.shield.scale.set(
  values.shieldScale.x,
  values.shieldScale.y,
  values.shieldScale.z
 );
 player2.pistol.scale.set(
  values.gunScale.x,
  values.gunScale.y,
  values.gunScale.z
 );
}

GameLoop();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I guess I have two questions:
1. Why does my three.js run slower when I load a server side file
2. How can I solve or get around this problem

Comment: That's a lot of code to read through to really get to the bottom of the issue. Any chance you could create a working example? You could use https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The code you have is embedding it in the file, not loading it via ajax Try loading the file via ajax after you have sent the html file. Then if you still have problems, maybe put the loading into a webworker

Comment: I have already tried loading the file with ajax and php, but both come up with the same result, and I have a working example at to-evangelos.000webhostapp.com/index.php